# How to store existing data in html table?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I am currently using thymeleaf, I have an array of server names to do a ssh connection that connects to the servers to obtain some values.

[image: values obtained]

Everytime I refresh, my application reruns. Which updates these values to the current values.

How can I save these values in a different page? That way it would allow me to compare current and previous values.

Answer (score 0):

You could [send an email](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html), assuming your server is set up correctly. I'm not seeing any way to save/create files.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to save those in a `JSON` File

[Simple JSON read and write](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/) from mykong